# es6 fetch request for salesforce desk api

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, salesforce, fetch-api

I am trying to set up public forms on a wp site so people can schedule an exam without a login, which is supposed to link to the clients salesforce desk app. the [Desk API docs](http://dev.desk.com/API/using-the-api/#general) recommend this.

```
$ curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/cases \
    -u email:password \
    -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -d '{"subject":"Test"}'
```

I admittedly have relied on es6 syntax for my inexperience with rest api calls and am having trouble validating my POST request. My javascript looks like so, but I get a 404 as well as a "Response to preflight check doesn't pass access control check." I'm assuming I am missing some credentials.

```
document.querySelector('#submitDesk').addEventListener('click', schedule);

function schedule() {
    var firstname = document.querySelector('#firstname').value;
    var lastname = document.querySelector('#lastname').value;
    var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;

    fetch('https://foo.desk.com/api/v2/cases', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            'firstname': firstname,
            'lastname': lastname,
            'email': email
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

Comment: A 404 indicates the server is responding with “not found” for the request to `https://foo.desk.com/api/v2/cases`. A 404 doesn’t indicate the request is missing credentials. If it were missing credentials and the server is configured correctly it would respond with a 401. But note that your server must not require credentials for that CORS preflight OPTIONS request the browser does—it must respond to that OPTIONS request with a 200 OK and the right CORS headers without any credentials being required. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. You're saying I probably don't even have the correct link?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you don’t have the correct link